# What is the correct Syntax for DataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted) In Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, ado.net

I'm trying to save data back to the database using Datatable. 
I have done this in C# but I can't figure out what the correct syntax in PowerShell to the following C# code

```
DataTable changeTable = table.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);
```

I tried the following PS script

```
$dtAdded = $Global:dtCalendars.GetChanges([DataRowState.Added])
```

it gave me the following error:
*Unable to find type [DataRowState.Added]*

Can anyone shed some light on this matter?

Thank you

Comment: `[System.Data.DataRowState]::Added`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum values are technically *static* fields of their respective enum type.

For this reason, you'll need to use the [*static member* operator (`::`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) to reference them:

```
[Namespace.TypeName]::ValueName
```

or, in your case:

```
[System.Data.DataRowState]::Added
```